# Was this idea used in Anderson’s The Man Who Counts based on a real life idea?

Tags: novel, inspiration, poul-anderson

In Poul Anderson's *The Man Who Counts* the heroes create ships made of ice to fight a battle at sea.  This is rather similar to a real world project conceived during WWII - [Project Habbakuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Habakkuk) to create ice aircraft carriers. Was Anderson inspired by the real project?